# BodyEditorLoader cannot be resolved to a type - Libgdx

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I am develooping a game in libgdx nightly realese, I want to use Physics Body Editor in my game, I am using Box2d in my game.

I have downloaded the loaders jars from http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/projects/physics-body-editor/ 
and tried to use threir example to load the json file.

it says that:

```
BodyEditorLoader cannot be resolved to a type
```

I have put the two jars "bodyeditor-loader.jar" and "bodyeditor-loader-sources.jar" in the android project build-path.

Someone know how to fix this? Someone have any idea?

Thank you, and sorry for m poor english.

Comment: Be sure to put the JARs in the `libs` subfolder and to add them to the classpath in Eclipse.

Comment: The jars are in the subfolder "libs", and I have put the jars in the project build path. Is it different from to add the jars in to the classpath ? If it is, how to add the jars in to the classpath ?
Thank you for replaying!